# "List iterators incompatible" when trying to erase an element from the list

Tags: c++, list, iterator

```
list<employee> remove_employees(const string& name,
                                const string& lastname) 
{
    list<employee> listOfRemoved; 
    list<employee>::iterator it; 

    for(it=employees.begin(); it != employees.end(); )
    {
        if(it->get_name() == name && it->get_lastname() ==lastname) 
        {
            listOfRemoved.push_back(*it); 
            employees.erase(it); 
        }
        else
            it++;
    }

    return listOfRemoved; 
}
```

I am trying to remove some employees from the class instance variable employees, and then return a new list, with only the deleted emeployees. When I try to run the program, it gives an error from the title. I know it has something to do with erasing, and pushing_back, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: usluzbenci.erase(it); was meant to be employees.erase(it), forgot it while I was translating the whole thing.

Comment: Can you post the compiler message in full, including line number? I just compiled this with VS2010 and VS2008 (after adding a simple `struct` for `employee`). The `.erase()` should store return value in `it` btw.

Comment: Debug assertion failed. Program: ....\vc\include\list\ Line: 286 Expression: list iterators incompatible

Comment: And compiled with g++ 4.3.4 http://ideone.com/CIdE9.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change:

```
employees.erase(it);
```

to:

```
it = employees.erase(it);
```

Otherwise on the next iteration of the loop `it` will be referring to an invalid element. [`list::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) returns the iterator following the last removed element.

[*I had interpreted the title as a compiler error, not a runtime error.*]